# Will deleting a cron job in CPANEL stop a running job?

Tags: cpanel, cron, laravel

I have a cron job in our CPANEL hosting. This is a laravel artisan command "queue:work". Now my problem is, the new code update is not reflecting unless I restart the command. I thought of deleting the cron job thinking it would stop the "queue:work" process from running I think I am wrong. I am still I'm seeing an outdated result. Eveything is working in my local machine. Please enlighten me with these questions:

1. The Cron Job is executed successfully and "queue:work" is running,
   will the process stop immediately once I delete the cron job for
   this command?
2. If not, How can I stop the existing "queue:work" process and start a new one?

Comment: Do you have command line access?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller unfortunately I have no SSH access due to restrictions